# Rick and Morty API (Angular)

Tags: angular, api, rest, typescript-typings, nginfinitescroll

I am trying to iterate some objects that this url give me: (https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character) in a gallery of cards using *ngFor[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c56pr.png)

this is the only way I've found to render my call and once I scroll down it changes the url of my call[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0fth.png)

The problem is that I don't want to refresh but I want to concatenate the results. I've already tried to transform the var "dataCharacter" in an array and then push the "res" in the array but the typing of interfaces and classes gives me some problems.

the service module[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEk3L.png) interface[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R33zR.png) class[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjP0Y.png)

Please someone can help me with creating the right classes and interfaces? I'm studing this for the first time and I don't know how to continue. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Character class should be renamed to CharacterResponse

The CharacterResults class should just be called Character

```
CharacterResponse {
   info: ...
   results: Array<Character>;
}
```

Your component class will then accumulate the characters

characters: Array = [];

```
subscribe((response: CharacterResult) => this.characters.push(...response.result));
```

template of course binds to characters array

Comment: Sorry, but I didn’t quite understand